# run query on sqlite using a Set string

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new with sqlite and database . I have an Set input.
when I Log it , It looks like this :

```
D/tag input: [item1,item2,item3,item4]
```

now I want to make a query whit these items on my database . But I get nothing from it . here is my query :

```
 cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from menu_items where menu_item_name=?", new String[]{input})
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong . Can someone help me on this case ?
Thanks

Comment: Is `input` an array or a string?

Comment: it is not array . it is string

Comment: Wrapped between square brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `input` is a string that contains a comma separated list of strings, you can't use the operators `=` or `IN`.

What you need is the operator `LIKE`.

If in the value of `input` there are also the square brackets:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM menu_items WHERE ',' || REPLACE(REPLACE(?, '[', ''), ']', '') || ',' LIKE '%,' || menu_item_name || ',%'", 
    new String[]{input}
);
```

If not then the code can be simplified:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM menu_items WHERE ',' || ? || ',' LIKE '%,' || menu_item_name || ',%'", 
    new String[]{input}
);
```

If there is a space after each comma:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM menu_items WHERE ', ' || ? || ', ' LIKE '%, ' || menu_item_name || ', %'", 
    new String[]{input}
);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response . for first query it shows an erorr  before run the query . "<expression> expected, got 'REPLACE'". for second one there is no error but it returns nothing .

Comment: I don't know how you run this code. Did you copy and paste it as it is? Check a demo that works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=489f871b5fdced541518547eb2d067ec

Comment: I tried to remove brackets manually and string look like something like this "item1,item2,item3,item4" . then I run second query . it works but it just returns one of them not all inputs .

Comment: Are there any spaces between the values and the commas?

Comment: yes . there is a space . after comma there is an space

Comment: Check my 3d query.

Comment: it works fine . thanks . it is second or third times you help me . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should use [IN](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-in/), something like

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from menu_items where menu_item_name in " +
"(" + Arrays.stream(input).map(e-> "'" + e + "'").collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + ")"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . 
I got error on 2 section . first one Arrays.stream(input)
with this error :
Cannot resolve method 'stream(java.lang.String)'
and Collectors.joining :
is for Api 24 and mine is 21 :

Comment: The idea is to have a string with the list `"('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4')"` , you can use other methods (like a for loop) to create it